# Getting bin for multiple json payloads via RPC abi_json_to_bin

Tags: rpc, abi

I'm trying to get the bin data for a multi action transaction similar to account creation but the RPC abi_json_to_bin doesn't seem to accept a list of json payloads. Is there a keyword/struct I should be passing to avoid the error?

The below code gives me the following error

{'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal Service Error', 'error': {'code': 7, 'name': 'bad_cast_exception', 'what': 'Bad Cast', 'details': [{'message': "Invalid cast from type 'array_type' to Object", 'file': 'variant.cpp', 'line_number': 573, 'method': 'get_object'}]}}

```
payload = [
        {
            "args": {
                "payer": creator,
                "receiver": new_acc_name,
                "bytes": 4096
            },
            "code": "eosio",
            "action": "buyrambytes",
            "authorization": [
                {
                    "actor": creator,
                    "permission": "active"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "args": {
                "from": creator,
                "receiver": new_acc_name,
                "stake_net_quantity": "0.1000 EOS",
                "stake_cpu_quantity": "0.1000 EOS",
                "transfer": 1
            },
            "code": "eosio",
            "action": "delegatebw",
            "authorization": [
                {
                    "actor": creator,
                    "permission": "active"
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question,

The bin data should be generated for each individual json in payload and appended in the actions field as a list.

The transaction will then be signed, packed and pushed.